# Attachment is not working in ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android

I'am using [file chooser library](https://github.com/ingyesid/simple-file-chooser) in my application. I have a attachment button in my CustomExpandableListAdapter. When I click the attachment button, It asks me to choose the file and upload it. I have followed the above link and written this code.

```
 Button attachment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attachment);
    attachment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context, FileChooserActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(_context, "inside attachment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((Activity) _context).startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER);     
        }
    }); 

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        String fileSelected = data.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_FILE_SELECTED);
        Toast.makeText(_context, "file selected "+fileSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                   
}
```

The application is stopped when i click that button. It shows ActivityNotFoundException. Please guide me how to declare it in manifest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to declare activity in manifest is write to your manifest file:

```
<activity 
            android:name="com.example.yourProject.ActivityName"
/>
```

If your activity is inner class of another class/activity you use $ symbol

```
.ActivityName$InnerActivity
```

For further reading about Activity and Manifest I would recomend

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html